# Django: my css static path does not exist

Tags: python, css, django

My link looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/background.css' %}">
```

This is fine because it gets the path I want which is href="/static/css/background.css".  I use {% load static}. I have django.contrib.staticfiles in my INSTALLED_APPS. This is some more relevant info on my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

But I'm pretty sure this is right too. My problem is that static/css/background.css cannot be found by my local server.  I know this because http://localhost:8000/static/css/background.css gives me a 404 error.  I don't know why this is the case because this is my project file path:

Project

```
  Project

  src

  static

     css
       background.css
```

Comment: I'm confused: do you want `static/css/background.css` or `static/background.css` ? One is inside the `css` subfolder and the other is not. Your question seems to mix them up...

Comment: @Ralf My bad, that was a typo. Fixed it.  static/css/background.css is the file path I want and what I am getting. It's just that the server can't find anything there.

Comment: Your whole URL should also include the subfolder, like this: `http://localhost:8000/static/css/background.css`. Does that also give 404 error?

Comment: @Ralf Yes, my bad I thought that was inferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem and I'm posting this in case anyone this can help anyone else.  My problem is that I had my static folder outside my app. It turns out that my website is targeting my app and so when django was looking for the static folder it was looking for it in my app. So try putting your static files in your app and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Have you set your url paths ? Here is a snippet from the official Django documentation.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I think if you have debug set to TRUE you can use `STATIC_FILE_ROOT="/my/path/to/static"` ... make sure you run `collectstatic` first though ( or something like that)

Comment: @h3k I Thought we didn't need to do that if we set up our settings.py right.  I thought STATIC_URL and django.contrib.staticfiles in settings would cover that.

Comment: @h3k which urls.py would I put that into? The one in my app or the one that is in my general project?

Comment: @TalhaAhmed you have to use the general project urls.py